# Javascript matches less than n occurances even thought it's explicitly set tomatch n

Tags: javascript, regex

Okay, so, I have this pattern

```
^(([0-9*\/]+)\s??){7}$
```

By default, it's supposed to match 7 segments that can have one of these sample forms:

```
[0/2, *, 2, /]
```

The problem is, this matches:

- `* * 0/2 * *` - incorrect
- `* * * * * * *` - correct
- `* 0/2 * * * 2 *` - correct
- `* 0/2 0/2` - incorrect

In C# I would just use ++ on the first capture group and it would work, but Javascript has an outdated regex that's missing key functionalities.

Here's the playground to reproduce: https://regex101.com/r/Pk23dV/1

Comment: You did not tell the regex engine to match 7 occurrences of whitespace separated entities. You only told it to match 7 occurrences of one or more digits, asterisks or slashes, the whitespace is optional (see `??` quantifier). More, you can't use `++` in C#, its regex engine does not support possessive quantifiers (still stuck at regex101 testing? regex101 does not support .NET regex flavor). Use `^[0-9*\/]+(?:\s[0-9*\/]+){6}$`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm not stuck at regex101, I got it to work for C#, this time I'm having difficulty with Javascript

Comment: But you could not use `++` in C#. Please share that part of C# code that worked in a comment, I'd love to see. Does `^[0-9*\/]+(?:\s[0-9*\/]+){6}$` solve the current problem the way you want? If you want to allow a trailing space add `\s?` before `$`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I haven't tested it yet on backend, I have yet to get frontend portion running (javascript)

Comment: Ok, just wanted to prevent another duplicate

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I understand. One was for C#, the other for Javascript - while they're related, I think they should have separate questions so they're easier to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `(([0-9*\/]+)\s??){7}$` pattern is of `^((a)b?){x}$` type where the `a` part is obligatory and `b` part is optional. That is, the `{7}` quantifier in your regex means there must be at least seven occurrences of a char matched with the `[0-9*\/]` pattern, whether consecutive or sepearated with whitespace.

If you wanted to write an expression where `\s` is obligatory in between `[0-9*\/]+` parts, you can use either

```js
^[0-9*\/]+(?:\s[0-9*\/]+){6}$
^(?:([0-9*\/]+)(?:\s(?!$)|$)){7}$
```

See the [regex demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/TFw0i4/1) and [regex demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/TFw0i4/2).

*Regex details*

- `^` - start of string
- `[0-9*\/]+(?:\s[0-9*\/]+){6}` - one or more digits, `/` or `*` and then six occurrences of a whitespace and then one or more digits, `/` or `*`
- `(?:([0-9*\/]+)(?:\s(?!$)|$)){7}` - seven occurrences of one or more digits, `/` or `*` followed with either a whitespace if not at the end of string or the end of string
- `$` - end of string.